# jQuery Hide ASP element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've explored multiple different guides to get an asp text box to hide when a button is clicked using JQuery client side.

However I still can't get it to work, I have tested it and a simpler code version worked with just html so I'm not sure what part of the asp isn't allowing this.

Thanks in advance.

Below is the jQuery and ASP

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TxtBx").hide();
        $('#btn2').click(function () {
            $('#TxtBx').toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel1">
    <br /><br />
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btn2" Text="Hide/Show" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBx" runat="server" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="20" Text="Something will go here"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Asp.Net, you might find that your IDs are being changed when the HTML is rendered. View the source of the page to see if this is true. Also, you will want to stop the default behaviour of the Button posting back to the server. Do this by passing the object `e` within your function and adding `e.preventDefault();`

In this case, you have a few options.

One. Change your jQuery code to get the correct ID from the element which is rendered. You do this with the code;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=(TxtBx.ClientID)%>").hide();
    $('#<%=(btn2.ClientID)%>').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the button from posting back the page.
        $('#<%=(TxtBx.ClientID)%>').toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Two. You can change your Asp.Net controls to use a [ClientIdMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Static`. This will render the HTML elements with the same ID that you have used within the control;

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="btn2" Text="Hide/Show" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBx" runat="server" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="20" Text="Something will go here" ClientIdMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Three. You can use Class names instead of Id's. This way Asp.Net will not change anything. e.g.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="btn2" Text="Hide/Show" runat="server" CssClass="btn2" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBx" runat="server" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="20" Text="Something will go here" CssClass="TxtBx"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>

$(document).ready(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the button from posting back the page.
    $(".TxtBx").hide();
    $('.btn2').click(function () {
        $('.TxtBx').toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks all working now (from your initial post). Went with option 1. Don't like accessing by class, and turning things to static seems detrimental. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access an asp.net control by the ID of the control unless you add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtBx" runat="server" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="20" Text="Something will go here" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now you can do this:

```
$("#TxtBx").hide();
```

If you don't use ClientIDMode, you can use the ClientID property to access it in jQuery.

```
$('#<%= TxtBx.ClientID %>').hide();
```