# JQuery ASP hidden issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Depending on the result of a checkbox, I want to hide/reveal a hidden table (hidden from page load), asking for more information.

The JQuery and ASP is below, can someone point me in the right direction and let me know what I'm doing wrong with this approach.

**ASP**

```
<h3>Table Heading</h3>
    <asp:Table ID="tbl1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <h4>One</h4>
            </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                    <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:CheckBox ID=""Yes" runat="server" Checked="false" Text="Yes" />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="No" Text="No" runat="server" Checked="false" />
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
    <asp:Table ID="tbl2" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <h4>Additional information</h4>
            </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="AddInfo" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleTable()
    {
        $(function () {
            $("#Yes").click(function () {
                $("#tbl2").show();
            })
            $("#No").click(function () {
                $("#tbl2").hide();
        })
    }
</script>
```

**Update 1**
As suggested I removed the wrapping function, this still didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () 
        {
            $("#Yes").click(function () {
                $("#tbl2").show();
        })
            $("No").click(function () {
                $("#tbl2").hide();
            })
        })
</script>
```

**Raw HTML**

```
<h3></h3>
    <table id="MainContent_tbl1">
<tr>
    <th>
                <h4></h4>
            </th>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="MainContent_Yes" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$Yes" value="Yes" />
    <label for="MainContent_Yes">Yes</label><input id="MainContent_No" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$No" value="No" />
    <label for="MainContent_No">No</label></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you had used `visible=false` in server control, that had done this - It removed that control entirely from page when rendered.

> More about Visible property - If this property is false, the server
>   control is not rendered. You should take this into account when
>   organizing the layout of your page. If a container control is not
>   rendered, any controls that it contains will not be rendered even if
>   you set the Visible property of an individual control to true. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible(v=vs.100).aspx

So i would suggest, if you are doing show/hide from server side code, then set attribute (CSS) style= display none . If you directly use visible property and set it to false, it will remove control from page, there will be no way to show in page.

E.g. `tbl1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");`

In client-side hide it using `style=display:none"` instead of `visible=false`.

Also, ,use `.ClientID` to get exact render ID for jquery selector. Like

`$("#<%=tbl1.ClientID%>").show();`

Comment: Thanks for that, I changed the server side section as there's no post back. However I can't get the JQuery section to work.

$(function () 
            {
                $("#<%=Yes.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                    $("#tbl2").show();
            })
                $("#<%=No.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                    $("#tbl2").hide();
                })
            })

Comment: You have already marked some post as answer, you are still facing issue? also recheck my answer i told you to use `$("#<%=tbl1.ClientID%>").show()` not `$("#tbl1").show();` - just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Take away the `toggleTable()` wrapping function and it should work as you've suggested.

The `$(function () {` runs when the document is ready and should turn on the click listeners at that point.

I'd also point out that the logic is flawed. Checkboxes can all be turned on so you might want to use radio buttons instead so only one can be checked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the question as that didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Could you post the RAW html that is spat out the other side?

Comment: Potentially you could need `ClientIDMode="Static"` in your page declaration to make all `runat="server"` items have the correct `id`

Comment: Raw HTML added to the question

Comment: Yes, as I thought. Read the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450939/jquery-hide-asp-element?rq=1) for ways to fix this issue. I suggest option 2, but set it globally instead of element by element.

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery get everthing by ClientID as it is asp it will rename it(as you can see it has added `MainContent_` to your control ids) so do this :

```
$("<%=tbl2.ClientID %>").click{....
```

Or add ClientIDMode = "Static" to your controls e.g.:

```
<asp:Table ID="tbl1" runat="server" ClientIDMode = "Static">
```